# Problems element the same class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

When a value is typed into any of the `jam` inputs, I want to use an `onkeyup` handler to take the value of only the `jam` input that generated the event. Then I want to use it to modify only the `Menit` input directly below it, not all of them.

Here is my code:

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".jam", function hitung_jam() {
  var jam = $(this).val();
  var waktu_jam = jam * 60;
  $(this).nextAll(".menit").first().val(waktu_jam);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="">
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td> KE 1 </td>
      <td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
    </tr>
    <hr>
    <tr>
      <td> KE 1 </td>
      <td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
      <td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Comment: please post your HTML

Comment: its is hard to understand what you mean

Answer (score 0):

This is for your HTML with the table.

```js
$(document).on("keyup", ".jam", function hitung_jam() {
 var jam = $(this).val();
 var waktu_jam = jam * 60;
 $(this).closest('tr').find('.menit').val(waktu_jam);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="POST" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td> KE 1 </td>
<td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
</tr>
<hr>
<tr>
<td> KE 1 </td>
<td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: if I add the table in the form of his jquery function does not work how?

but if you do not use table function

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work, since I can't see your table.  If you  needed a table you should have put it in the question.  The '.menit' selector assumes that the appropriate input will be a sibling of the `.jam`.  I assume they are in different rows, so that assumption is probably incorrect.  It would need to change to perhaps `$(this).closest('tr').findAll('.menit').first()`

Comment: <form method="POST" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td> KE 1 </td>
<td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
</tr>
<hr>
<tr>
<td> KE 1 </td>
<td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

Comment: this:
<form method="POST" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td> KE 1 </td>
<td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
</tr>
<hr>
<tr>
<td> KE 1 </td>
<td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>

Comment: @DoloveIgo Not happy with this moving target.  No more changes.

Answer (score 0):

if I add the table in the form of his jquery function does not work how? but if you do not use table function

```
<form method="POST" action="">
<table>
<tr>
<td> KE 1 </td>
<td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
</tr>
<hr>
<tr>
<td> KE 1 </td>
<td> Jam <input type="text" class="jam" autocomplete="off"></td>
<td> Menit <input type="text" class="menit"> </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<script>

$(document).on("keyup", ".jam", function hitung_jam() {
var jam = $(this).val();
    var waktu_jam = jam * 60;
    $(this).nextAll(".menit").first().val(waktu_jam);
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use siblings:

```
 $(this).siblings(".menit").val(waktu_jam);
```

Check: [jQuery Siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)